# Display list images from database in razor

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an ASP.NET application and I'm using Razor, I want to display multiple images  in my view . I have already stored those images in Database . 
My code can display only one image.

I have a table in the db, which has the following :- Id, image, ... and I want to display the image only, I am trying to display the image in the index and I have the following in the View :

```
 <img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Image", new {id=3})"  />
```

and in the ImageController I have :

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
using (var db = new Bd_scanitEntities())
{
var firstOrDefault = db.ImgOrgSet.Where(
                                        c => c.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();

if (firstOrDefault != null)
   if (firstOrDefault != null)
      {
       byte[] image = firstOrDefault.image;
       return File(image, "image/jpg");
       }
       else
       {
        return null;
       }
}

return View();
}
```

Can you help me in order to the display all the images contained in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view do a `for` loop and call the Action method with `id= index`. If you show me your code of the view I can Explicit my explanantion with your code
If the id in the table in database is not incremented, it will better to use a `foreach` loop. Let's say you delete an image and then add another image in your table. I think the index will not correspond to the `Count` property.

Answer (score 0):

**1st Approach**

Get ImagesList from database like the way you are getting one from you action and populate them dynamically, here is chunk of code, which will give you some idea, how to accomplish:

```
@foreach(var ID in Ids)
{
<img src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Image", new {id=ID})"  /> 
}
```

**2nd Approach**

another way is instead of storing image in database store its path and render them at runtime, using same way just pass path in `src` attribute